# Not getting namespaces- System.Data,System.Web.Services in Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8

I tried to create a Windows Phone library and tried to create a class in Windows Phone but I cannot access namespaces such as `System.Data,System.Web.Services` etc.

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 2):

The `System.Web.Services` namespace is not available on windows phone 8 and `System.Data` is alot smaller than in the complete .Net framework.

Compare: [WP8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.data%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) and [.Net 4.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.aspx)

This might be why you cant find your namespaces.

See: [API Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff626516%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) for available namespaces.